# Set and get environment variable in WINXP and WIN 7

Tags: vb.net

I am wondering if I can use VB.NET(I am using visual studio 2010 express) to get and set a environment variable.

I want to add path of my application on system environment. I want to preserve what is already there and then I wan to add my string. 
This can be done by getting value of PATH and then append my string then re writing it.

I have 2 questions here:

1. How to get/set system variable in vb.net 2010?
2. Will it be on the fly, I mean will it be immediatly avaialble in dos prompt or there will be delay?

As  just for experiment i opened a command prompt then updated the `PATH` variable manually and it was not updated. I am wondering it I do it through programe it will be same.

I hope i stated my problem clearly, please feel free to comment to ask if need more clarity.

Comment: @Tim, Hans has told in his reply that it will be process space specific. change will lost as process exits or die. While I was searching on the internet. I found something like your answer but never told that it update the system variable to registry. Can you please tell me if this change through Environment will be actually updated in the registry and will be permanent.

Comment: Try it yourself ;) According to the sample in [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx#Y1575) the Environment-Variables are written to the registry("Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current process or in the Windows operating system registry key reserved for the current user or local machine.").

Comment: Sure I will do. Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following methods:

- [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx)
- [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable.aspx)

Environment-Methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yat6s6yb.aspx

Also note the optional third parameter in:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(variable,value,EnvironmentVariableTarget)
```

Possible values are: Machine, Process and User

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx